Definition and Use of the Schett Polynomial in the Jacobi Taylor Series
I am having a tough time understanding the definition and use of the Schett polynomial introduced in the paper here. I have two questions related to this polynomial. My first question concerns its definition in the context of the Taylor series of the Jacobi elliptic functions. My second question is what the definition of $cn(u,x)$ and $sn(u,x)$ are using the Schett polynomial $S_n(x,y,z)$, which is also discussed in another paper here. The most clear use of the polynomial to define $sn(u,x)$ that I have come across is:
$$\frac{1}{ia}sn\left(iau,\frac{b}{a}\right)=\frac{1}{ab}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}S_{2n+1}(0,a,b)\frac{u^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
Can a Schett polynomial with odd and even components be added together? For example,
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}S_{2n}(0,a,b)+\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}S_{2n+1}(0,a,b)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}S_{n}(0,a,b)$$
I want to better understand the relationship between the argument in the polynomial and how that relates to $sn(u,x)$ and $cn(u,x)$, like what would happen if you used $S_{2n+1}(a,b,c,d)$ instead of $S_{2n+1}(0,a,b)$ in the definition of $sn(u,x)$. This may seem like a lot more than two questions, but I am just looking for a good understanding on how to use these polynomials. The papers that exist on these polynomials are not easily digestible at my level of understanding, and I would greatly appreciate any help that can be offered.
